# Scrapy XHR Pagination on TripAdvisor

Tags: python, xpath, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

Although I've seen several similar questions here regarding this, none seem to precisely define the process for achieving this task. I borrowed largely from the Scrapy script located [here](https://github.com/monkeylearn/hotel-review-analysis/blob/master/hotel_sentiment/spiders/tripadvisor_spider.py) but since it is over a year old I had to make adjustments to the xpath references.

My current code looks as such:

```
import scrapy
from tripadvisor.items import TripadvisorItem

class TrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'trspider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g29217-Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii-Hotels.html'
        ]

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="listing_title"]/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotel)

    next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="unified pagination standard_pagination"]/child::*[2][self::a]/@href')
    if next_page:
        url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

def parse_hotel(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div[starts-with(@class,"quote")]/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_review)

    next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="unified pagination "]/child::*[2][self::a]/@href')
    if next_page:
        url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_hotel)

def parse_review(self, response):
    item = TripadvisorItem()
    item['headline'] = response.xpath('translate(//div[@class="quote"]/text(),"!"," ")').extract()[0][1:-1]
    item['review'] = response.xpath('translate(//div[@class="entry"]/p,"\n"," ")').extract()[0]
    item['bubbles'] = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating")]/@alt').extract()[0]
    item['date'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]/@content)').extract()[0]
    item['hotel'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="altHeadInline"]/a/text())').extract()[0]
    return item
```

When running the spider in its current form, I scrape the first page of reviews for each hotel listed on the `start_urls` page but the pagination doesn't flip to the next page of reviews. From what I suspect, this is because of this line:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="unified pagination "]/child::*[2][self::a]/@href')
```

Since these pages load dynamically, there is no existing `href` for the next page on the current page. Investigating further I've read that these requests are sending a `POST` request using `XHR`. By exploring the `"Network"` tab in Firefox "Inspect" I can see both a `Request URL` and `Form Data` that might be needed to flip the page according to other posts on SO regarding the same topic.

However, it seems that the other posts refer to a static URL starting point when trying to pass a `FormRequest` using Scrapy. With TripAdvisor, the URL will always change based on the name of the hotel we're looking at so I'm not sure how to chose a URL when using `FormRequest` to submit the form data: `reqNum=1&changeSet=REVIEW_LIST` (this form data also never seems to change from page to page).

Alternatively, there doesn't appear to be a way to extract the URL shown in the `"Network"` tab's `"Request URL"`. These pages *do* have URLs that change from page to page but the way TripAdvisor is set up, I cannot seem to extract them from the source code. The review pages change by incrementing the part of the URL that is `-orXX-` where `"XX"` is a number. For example:

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2312116-d113123-Reviews-Fairmont_Orchid_Hawaii-Puako_Kohala_Coast_Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii.html

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2312116-d113123-Reviews-or5-Fairmont_Orchid_Hawaii-Puako_Kohala_Coast_Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii.html

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2312116-d113123-Reviews-or10-Fairmont_Orchid_Hawaii-Puako_Kohala_Coast_Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii.html

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2312116-d113123-Reviews-or15-Fairmont_Orchid_Hawaii-Puako_Kohala_Coast_Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii.html
```

So, my question is whether or not it is possible to paginate using the XHR request/form data or do I need to manually build a list of URLs for each hotel that adds the `-orXX-`?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote? Can someone explain what I should specify better in my question to avoid the hit to my SO rep?

Answer (score 1):

Well I ended up discovering an xpath that apparently allowed pagination of the reviews, but it's funny because every time I checked the underlying HTML the href link never changed from referring to `/Hotel_Review-g2312116-d113123-Reviews-or5-Fairmont_Orchid_Hawaii-Puako_Kohala_Coast_Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii.html` even if I was on page 10 for example. It seems the "-orXX-" part of the link always increments the XX by 5 so I'm not sure why this works.

All I did was change the line:
    `next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="unified pagination "]/child::*[2][self::a]/@href')`

to:
    `next_page = response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href')`

and have >41K extracted reviews. Would love to get other's opinions on handling this problem in other situations.